# display a binary stream fetched from database as "image" inside the html as an <img> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to display an image which is fetched from the database as a binary stream, on the web form. Can you shed some light on this!

I am working on a project where users have profiles, and every user have their own profile picture displayed in the home page. THis picture comes from the database.

here is the code i have used to get the stream !

```
TestDBDataContext context1 = new TestDBDataContext();

            var r = (from a in context1.ImageTables where a.Id == 8 select a).First();

           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(r.FileImage.ToArray());
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've done in the past is set the image url to an aspx page, like so:

```
<img src="getLogo.aspx" alt="Logo" />
```

Then, in the code-behind for getLogo.aspx, I've done the following:

```
Response.BinaryWrite( imageData );
Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
```

Where `imageData` is your image as a byte array

Comment: No, no data is being sent back through a POST.

Comment: No POST because the page with the image tag doesn't even know it's calling an aspx page for the image it's just writing "the image uri". The page that said the image likewise doesn't know or care how it was called. They're both nicely separated from each other.

Answer (score 8):

Base64 encode your binary and insert in an image tag as follows (change the mimetype to suit):

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,BASE64 ENCODED BINARY HERE">
```

This is how you would do it, but I would not do this as some browsers cannot handle it (IE6). You are better off saving to a file first and doing it the conventional way.

Comment: I see , so other than saving the image and linking to that , is there any other way to do this ? say may be using an httphandler or somethn ?

Comment: I think that DJ Quimby has the right approach, in PHP I would create a script that would take the image name as a query parameter, retrieve the binary from the datastore and return it to the browser, setting a content-type header with the correct mimetype.

Answer (score 3):

I would save the image to a directory within the website that is accessible to external callers (i.e. an images subdirectory) using a nonsense name (such as the primary key of the record in the database or a GUID), then add an href to this file in the web page.

Comment: thanks , but  If i were to do that why wud i save in the database at all ? I know thats an approach of doing that but I am looking for something better, any idea?

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz: A few reasons I can think of: 1) You may eventually have multiple web servers, so you don't have to coordinate files on each; 2) You may migrate to a new web server or platform, so again not have to manage files is worthwhile; 3) if the images represent something related to the business, you may need/want to represent them in a different client, such as silverlight or a tablet app.

Comment: Yes, but given all those reasons (they've already chosen to save it in DB) why have it as a file in the webroot? That's a bit weird.

Comment: @JonHanna: It's a transient activity to serve up a file. We use this mechanism extensively to server generated images and files, such as thumbnails of documents, reports, charts, etc. We regularly clean out the temp directory so that we don't have stale data, but this has worked very well for us.

Comment: I use it with server-gen images I'll want to reuse a lot, as it acts as a cache to the operation, but not if it's in the DB as is or won't be repeatedly called. Why just add two more file operations rather than write the image in the first place?

Comment: Wait? How are you even going to know what href to add to the page unless you generate the image in the actual page that uses it?

Comment: @JonHanna: re href: That depends on the business logic for the site. For example, if you generate a report and the user is on the report page, you display the image associated with the generated report.

Comment: @JonHanna: re file operations: again, depends on business logic. Going back to reports, if we have a web farm and thick clients that all require the same image and the image is expensive to generate, then it is stored in the DB. Another example is client-specific logos; our customers can customize the site using a logo that they upload through an admin tool and this can vary based on their customer. There is no reason to extract all customer logos to a given web server, so we wait until one is requested, then extract and cache.

Answer (score 1):

Save Memory Stream to file using:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
     using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
     {
       memoryStream.SaveTo(fileStream);
     }
```

Then put filename in html.

Comment: i am sorry, but i didnt get your point here, can you please explain a lil bit ?

Answer (score 1):

First have a separate .aspx file for the image (actually I'd favour an IHttpHandler overload for this, but the principle's the same and let's introduce only one new concept at a time).

The .aspx file will just inherit from the code-behind, and have no content. So it would have the `<%@ Page %>` directive and nothing else.

In the code-behind, in the page-load event-handler, obtain the image, and set the content-type of the response to the appropriate value (or if e.g. all the images are image/png, you could just hard-code that). Then write the image to the output.

```
TestDBDataContext context1 = new TestDBDataContext();
int id;
if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id))
{
  var r = (from a in context1.ImageTables where a.Id == 8 select a).FirstOrDefault();
  if(r != null)
  {
    Response.ContentType = r.ContentType;
    Response.BinaryWrite(r.FileImage.ToArray());
    return;
  }
}
//code to handle 404 not found for no such image here (send error message or Server.Transfer to error page, etc.
```

Then you can use this with `<img src="profileImg.aspx?id=8" alt="" />` etc.

A performance improvement is to obtain bytes a 4k chunk at a time from the database and write them to `Response.OutputStream`, rather than one massive array in memory. For small files the difference is unimportant, but for very large files it can be considerable (as in "hurray now my webserver isn't falling over repeatedly any more!" considerable).

Comment: If i were to do this in an httphandler what would be the difference ?

Comment: It's slightly lighter and cleaner in the case where you are pretty much just doing one simple task in the response. Actually, aspx pages are all IHttpHandler implementations anyway, with a bunch of other useful functionality. Once you're happy you know how to solve your current issue, I recommend trying it the HttpHandler way. Quite likely the first time it'll seem like an extra complication, but once your used to them they can seem simpler for cases like this.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend just using a page right now though. As said, you'll find IHttpHandlers a cleaner and easier way to do things like this when you're used to them, but it's always best to try one new thing at a time. Otherwise if you hit a problem you may not even know which of the two is causing you the problem!

Comment: can i also use a web service to deliver the src ?

Comment: You could. If you were using a webservice to deliver information about the user you could include the URI for their profile with that. Note that because you can have the image-serving page look up the appropriate image, you don't need any image-related logic when returning the src, you just take a string like "/somePath/profileImage.aspx?id=" and add on the relevant ID number.

Comment: why does this code not work then ?

    <img runat="server" src="~/Testingfiles/uploadify/uploadify.ashx?id=15" alt="" />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5920/discussion-between-jon-hanna-and-shane-adrian-muaz)